# SQL Query return only NULL results on associative table

Tags: sql, database

I have 3 tables (People, ProjectGroupAssoc and Projects), and I'm looking to show all people who **do not** have a specific project_Id. As in, I would like to have the query return the person's name but NULL in the project_id, and project_name columns.

**EDITED**
Let's say Tim should be assigned a 'Database' project; however, he currently doesn't have a database assignment in the ProjectGroupAssoc table. How would one query Tim, and any other "people" who don't have 'Database' projects, without returning multiple row for each `person` (i.e. returning just those people with `NULL` for database projects, and not the other projects they have been assigned?

This is to ensure certain "people" have been assigned their respective projects for tracking and auditing. Here's my sample database/tables/relationships.

```
create table People (
    person_Id int,
    name varchar(255)
);

INSERT INTO People (person_Id, name)
VALUES (0, 'John'), (1, 'Paul'), (2, 'Tim');

create table ProjectGroupAssoc (    
    person_Id int, 
    groupId int
);

INSERT INTO ProjectGroupAssoc (person_Id, groupId)
VALUES (0, 255), (1, 1700), (2, 35), (0, 17), (0, 333), (1, 255)

CREATE TABLE Projects ( 
    proj_Id int, 
    p_name varchar(255)
);

INSERT INTO Projects(proj_Id, p_name)
VALUES (255, 'Database'), (1700, 'Development'), (333, 'Training'), 
(35, 'security'), (17, 'analytics')

select p.person_Id, p.name, pga.groupId, pro.p_name
from People p
left join ProjectGroupAssoc pga on p.person_Id = pga.person_Id
left join Projects pro on pga.groupId = pro.proj_Id    
where pga.groupId = 255;
```

Comment: What's wrong with the query you have?

Comment: Is just a suggestion but for `ProjectGroupAssoc` instead you should call the field names `people_id, project_id` calling everything `Id` can be confusing.

Comment: What is the result you expect ? because we dont know anything about `certain "people"` Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: You have the query already? You just need to change your where clause to check for a null project i.e. `where pro.Id is null`

Comment: I don't want to return multiple rows for each `person_id`, though (this is a one to many relationship, i.e. one person can have many `project_id's`. I am trying to narrow down to one result per name, where the `project_id` does not exist for that `person_id`; rather than return every result for each `person_id`, including null results.If that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for something like this.

```
  select p.Id, p.name, pga.groupId, pro.p_name
  from People p
  left join ProjectGroupAssoc pga on p.Id = pga.Id AND pga.groupId = 255
  left join Projects pro on pga.groupId = pro.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want show people who **do not** have a project id

```
SELECT p.person_Id
FROM People p
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ProjectGroupAssoc pga WHERE p.person_Id = pga.person_Id AND pga.groupId = 255)
```